# How to Connect from cURL to Rest API USPS portal?

Tags: bash, api, curl, usps

I am trying to connect to [USPS portal](https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/address-information-api.htm#_Toc16515165) using curl command.

In hadoop its working fine.

```
curl -i "https://secure.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=Verify&XML=<AddressValidateRequest USERID="XXXXXXXXX">"
* About to connect() to secure.shippingapis.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 56.0.34.44...
* Connected to secure.shippingapis.com (56.0.34.44) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* Server certificate:
*       subject: CN=secure.shippingapis.com,OU=Unified Communications,OU=Hosted by United States Postal Service,OU=WebTools,O=United States Postal Service,STREET=2825 Lone Oak Parkway,L=Eagan,ST=MN,postalCode=55121,C=US
*       start date: May 24 00:00:00 2019 GMT
*       expire date: May 23 23:59:59 2020 GMT
*       common name: secure.shippingapis.com
*       issuer: CN=COMODO SHA-256 Organization Validation Secure Server CA,O=COMODO CA Limited,L=Salford,ST=Greater Manchester,C=GB
> GET /ShippingAPI.dll?API=Verify&XML=<AddressValidateRequest USERID=XXXXXXXXX> HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: secure.shippingapis.com
> Accept: */*
```

However when i try to send a request and get response back from server, it is unable to do so .

```
curl -i -X GET AddressValidateRequest.txt "https://secure.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=Verify&XML=<AddressValidateRequest USERID="XXXXXXXXXXXX">
<Address>
<Address1>6406 IVY LANE</Address1>
<Address2></Address2>
<City>GREENBELT</City>
<State>TX</State>
<Zip5>20770</Zip5>
<Zip4></Zip4>
</Address>
</AddressValidateRequest>"
```

Answer (score 1):

USERID - usps shiping authentication ID

> curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -d > 'API=RateV4&XML=<RateV4Request USERID="**USERID**"><Revision>2</Revision><Package ID="1ST"><Service>Priority Mail Express</Service><FirstClassMailType>PACKAGE SERVICE RETAIL</FirstClassMailType><ZipOrigination>33016</ZipOrigination><ZipDestination>35004</ZipDestination><Pounds>1</Pounds><Ounces>0</Ounces><Container/><Width>1</Width><Length>1</Length><Height>1</Height><Machinable>true</Machinable></Package></RateV4Request>' -X POST 'https://secure.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll'

Answer (score 0):

XML is typically not appended to the end of a URL, but your quotes are off since you have double quotes within double quotes.

Also try removing all the whitespace, and not sure what `AddressValidateRequest.txt` is trying to do

You can also remove the `-i -v -X GET` if you only want to see the response

```
curl 'https://secure.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=Verify&XML=<AddressValidateRequest USERID="XXXXXXXXXXXX"><Address>...</Address></AddressValidateRequest>'
```

Comment: I am still not able to get response from the server USPS I tried sending the following request: Can you please help?    curl -i -v -X GET "https://secure.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=Verify&XML=<AddressValidateRequest USERID="XXXXXXXXX"><Address><Address1>6406 IVY LANE</Address1><Address2></Address2><City>GREENBELT</City><State>TX</State><Zip5>20770</Zip5><Zip4></Zip4></Address></AddressValidateRequest>"

Comment: * About to connect() to secure.shippingapis.com port 443 (#0)
* Connected to secure.shippingapis.com 
* SSL connection using TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* Server certificate:
*       subject: CN=secure.shippingapis.com,OU=Unified Communications,OU=Hosted by United States Postal Service,OU=WebTools,O=United States Postal Service,STREET=2825 Lone Oak Parkway,L=Eagan,ST=MN,postalCode=55121,C=US
*       common name: secure.shippingapis.com
*       issuer: CN=COMODO SHA-256 Organization Validation Secure Server

Comment: CA,O=COMODO CA Limited,L=Salford,ST=Greater Manchester,C=GB
> GET /ShippingAPI.dll?API=Verify&XML=<AddressValidateRequest USERID=XXXXXXXX><Address><Address1>6406 IVY LANE</Address1><Address2></Address2><City>GREENBELT</City><State>TX</State><Zip5>20770</Zip5><Zip4></Zip4></Address></AddressValidateRequest> 
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Connection: close
Cache-Control: no-cache,no-store Pragma: no-cache
* Closing connection 0

Comment: I don't know how their API works... Nor do I have a USER_ID to test anything. Could you show any documentation that includes what requests should look like?

Comment: This is response that I got when i executed above request locally <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<AddressValidateResponse>
<Address>
<Address2>6406 IVY LN</Address2>
<City>GREENBELT</City>
<State>MD</State>
<Zip5>20770</Zip5>
<Zip4>1441</Zip4>
</Address>
</AddressValidateResponse>

Comment: You can also register if you want https://registration.shippingapis.com/

Comment: Based on your first comment, you again messed up the quotations. Your userid has double quotes. You can't surround the URL with double quotes, then

Comment: And are you using curl locally as well?

Comment: No I am not using curl locally just single quotes inner part we can execute locally. However I tried using curl in hadoop cluster still its not working. curl -i -X GET 'https://secure.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=Verify&XML=<AddressValidateRequest USERID="XXXXXXXXX"><Address><Address1>6406 IVY LANE</Address1><Address2></Address2><City>GREENBELT</City><State>TX</State><Zip5>20770</Zip5><Zip4></Zip4></Address></AddressValidateRequest>'

Comment: Can you please help here?

Comment: Again, my suggestion is to get curl working on another machine. I doubt your issue is Hadoop